# unable to verify using ecrecover - EIP 712 Simple multisig

Tags: contract-development, multisignature

I am signing a random message with the private key using web3.eth.accounts.sign('test',privatekey). This is returning me v,r,s,message hash and signature. I am feeding v,r,s to "execute" function in contract.

I am able to deploy and execute transaction using EIP 712 Smart contract. However ecrecover function is returning some other address. I am not sure what need to be passed in "data" parameter in the execute function. I am passing message hash which might be the issue.

Request you to please suggest the correct approach.

EIP 712 contract - https://github.com/christianlundkvist/simple-multisig/blob/master/contracts/SimpleMultiSig.sol

Thanks much.

Comment: What is the value of your `v`?

Comment: 0x1b - converted to uint : 27

Comment: Then try to pass `Number(v) - 27` (which will also support the possibility of `v == '0x1c'`).

Comment: var sign1 = web3.eth.accounts.sign('test','0xa99fb0c634b13322f47de04504a7428d41aec16d1ffb48ea8641e3f149a64cb6');
{
  message: 'test',
  messageHash: '0x4a5c5d454721bbbb25540c3317521e71c373ae36458f960d2ad46ef088110e95',
  v: '0x1b',
  r: '0x8b47c0834654b7ff8869c170b7e92a4203a8e9d5edbe74c9736d525e5553ec90',
  s: '0x28721b7fc5cbfdb4f63f45847f871324c70f23fcaff00a257a5479c7a6198ace',
  signature: '0x8b47c0834654b7ff8869c170b7e92a4203a8e9d5edbe74c9736d525e5553ec9028721b7fc5cbfdb4f63f45847f871324c70f23fcaff00a257a5479c7a6198ace1b'
}

Comment: That should throw a runtime error regardless of the value of `v`, because the contract function expects a `uint8`, while you are passing it a `string`.

Comment: Worse, it expects an array of `uint8` (and another two arrays of `bytes32`), so I sincerely hope that you are passing each one of those values inside `[]`. In any case, note that the `v` values should be passed as numbers.

Comment: Passing these parameters to execute function in contract:                                              
v - [27]
sigR - ["0x8b47c0834654b7ff8869c170b7e92a4203a8e9d5edbe74c9736d525e5553ec90"]
sigS - ["0x28721b7fc5cbfdb4f63f45847f871324c70f23fcaff00a257a5479c7a6198ace"]
destination - "0x8206DEDd4BC0d83a116DE74C6D948932ffc8aBe3"
value - 99999999
data - "0x4a5c5d454721bbbb25540c3317521e71c373ae36458f960d2ad46ef088110e95"
gaslimit - 6721975
executor - "0xb6C129D84Edac56DC99cd546586ED63522e98385"

Comment: Cool. That looks correct. So try `[Number(v) - 27]` instead of `[Number(v)]`.

Comment: sorry, did not get you.. i am passing [27], I should pass something else?

Comment: Try `[0]` (and more generally, since `v` is not always `'0x1b'`, use `[Number(v) - 27]`).

Comment: passed [0] in sigV . Now ecrecover is giving 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 as output instead of some random address.

Comment: Is there any dependency on TXTYPE_HASH (line 55) . these variables seem hardcoded values in contract